# What are the security and performance constraints of using docker containers in a RESTful API in order to execute untrusted code?

Tags: performance, rest, security, docker

I am developing a set of RESTful APIs for providing some data analytics. When calling the API, the client will also be able to pass script functions as additional parameters (and the functions will be executed during the analytics pipeline). The data itself will be retrieved from various sources such as Amazon S3, The client's Dropbox, or Google cloud storage.

I want to be able to execute the client scripts in a very controlled and segregated environment.

I was therefore thinking of instantiating a docker container for each client request, and executing the processing pipeline as well as the client scripts in that controlled environment.

So basically, the RESTful endpoints would dynamically instantiate docker containers in order to process the client requests. When done, the processing results will be pushed back to Dropbox/S3/Google Cloud Storage  and at that point the corresponding docker container would also be removed or reallocated to another request).

**Edit 1**:

- From the RESTful API point of view, the client requests will be accepted (HTTP 202) and pushed into a processing queue.
- Every request in the processing queue will be in turn assigned to a docker container at some point in the future. The client will be able to query the status of the processing using another RESTful endpoint.

**Edit 2**: Here is a link explaining a similar approach: https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/sandboxing-code-in-the-era-of-containers-294edb3a674#.19882q2g5

My questions:

- What are the performance impacts for such an approach. In other words, what are the performance costs of systematically creating docker containers for the processing instead of using worker processes.
- Does this approach really adds an extra level of security?

Comment: You considered that your API is not going to handle the HTTP calls only but it will need to orchestrate somehow the resources (containers) in a manner that  actually makes sense, so resources are used effectively (not to mention efficiently), right? Can we know what is the benefit you foresee by isolating processes in a virtualized layer vs. sending your calls to a background task (e.g. workers)? I believe there is more to be told before anyone can come with a proper answer not to say a clever one.

Comment: @monchitos82 Yes the API will have to do some form of orchestration and resource management. And yes I could have background tasks as you suggested. And I also expect that those tasks will run for a period of time. The point of specifically using a docker container is really to add an extra level of security. I don't want the client's scripts to simply run "in the wild". I am assuming that by correctly configuring a docker image, I can mitigate security risks by  having client scripts execute in a contained environment.

Comment: That's a legit concern. I'm not positive about the idea of creating and destroying containers for running scripts is the biggest win (performance wise) for a REST API... found this URL: https://thehftguy.com/2016/11/01/docker-in-production-an-history-of-failure/ not sure it will help but it shares some unsavory experiences. I'd go for a proof of concept where I forward processing to a VM and run those in a chroot approach and see if that covers my needs, but that's just an idea.